# Running a single .feature file

Tags: karate

I'd like to run a single .feature file, the one I'm trying to debug, instead of the full set of over 100 tests we have... it it possible?

I'v tried adding the "classpath" to the karate options, as I saw in other answers, but it still runs everything even if the path doesn't exists:

```
$ mvn clean test \
   -Dtest=ParallelTest \
   -DargLine="-Dkarate.options='--tags  ~@ignore classpath:relative/path/to/my/new.feature" \
   -Denv='dev'
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Could you please edit your question to add more details about the environment you're using, language, and perhaps the contents of the .feature file?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the IDE support is for, we have Visual Studio Code (recommended), IntelliJ and Eclipse: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/IDE-Support

If you are interested in the details, there is a "CLI way" to do this (0.9.5 onwards): https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Debug-Server#maven - so just put a feature `classpath:` instead of the `-d`

And for Maven / JUnit users, most teams write a "Runner" class, and you can add a test method and run a single feature, please refer to the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#junit-5